C# - Dynamic predicate inside .Select() throws expection
I have next domain models:
public class UserTask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<TaskHistory> TaskHistories { get; set; } = new List<TaskHistory>();
}

public class TaskHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserTaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual UserTask UserTask { get; set; } = new List<UserTask>();
}

Then in the business logic I want to use dynamic dynamic predicates. But I'm facing a problem in my execution. Where the business logic looks next way:
...
Expression<Func<UserTask, bool>> taskPredicate = (t => t.Name == "ABC");
Func<TaskHistory, bool> taskHistoryPredicate = (th => th.Name == "ABC");

queryable = (IOrderedQueryable<UserTask>)context.UserTasks.
        .Include(t => t.TaskHistories)
        .Where(taskPredicate)
        .Select(t => new UserTask()
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name,
            // other properties...
            TaskHistories = (ICollection<TaskHistory>) t.TaskHistories.Where(taskHistoryPredicate) // <- this doesn't work
            //TaskHistories = (ICollection<TaskHistory>) t.TaskHistories.Where(th => th.Name == "ABC") // <- this works
        });
        
List<UserTasks> tasks = queryable.ToList();
...

In situation when it converts into list it throws an exception:

System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Func2[TestPredicate.TaskHistory,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2[TestPredicate.TaskHistory,System.Boolean]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[TestPredicate.TaskHistory] Where[TaskHistory](System.Linq.IQueryable1[TestPredicate.TaskHistory], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func`2[TestPredicate.TaskHistory,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg1')

I can't understand why when I use hardcoded predicate it works, but then I inserting it from a variable it does not. I also tried to change Func<,> into Expression<Func<,>> and execute taskHistoryPredicate.Compile(), same error.

You need to replace the Expression<Func<TaskHistory, bool>> in the resulting expression. I recommend using LINQKit for this. LINQKit allows you to use the Invoke method to substitute the expression. Here is an example of how you can do this:
Expression<Func<UserTask, bool>> taskPredicate = (t => t.Name == "ABC");

queryable = (IOrderedQueryable<UserTask>)context.UserTasks
        .Include(t => t.TaskHistories)
        .Where(taskPredicate)
        .Select(t => new UserTask
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name,
            // other properties...
            TaskHistories = (ICollection<TaskHistory>)t.TaskHistories.Where(t => taskPredicate.Invoke(t))
        });
        
List<UserTask> tasks = queryable.ToList();

Activate LINQKit during options configuration:
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension

